# portaudio is lagging while reading/recording

Tags: pyaudio, portaudio

I have compiled and installed portaudio19 but it lags badly while recording.

It can be reproduced using:

```
pamon | pacat -p
```

or python code using pyaudio

```
import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024 * 2
FORMAT = pa.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000

p = pa.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)


while 1:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    stream.write(data)
```

Tried diff settings for everything.

I have tried a number of settings and tweaks related to portaudio latency and also tried different things that uses portaudio like pyaudio etc.. but no love.

When trying "alsa or pulse" there is no latency so everything else should be ok.

I'm using a generic 5.10 kernel on Ubuntu 18.04.6

My goal is use pyaudio, as the other python audio modules uses portaudio I see no alternative.

PS: pamon/pacat has nothing to do with portaudio, what confuses me because I have tried audacity with pulse and it works just fine.

ALSA version 1.1.3
Portaudio stable from git v190700 2021 04 06

Comment: `pamon` and `pacat` have nothing to do with portaudio; the `pa` is for `pulseaudio`. Portaudio is just a thin wrapper around native audio libraries, so now I'm doubly confused about this question: It seems to be about latency of a **pulse**audio system (which wouldn't be on-topic here), but you seem to be planning to use `portaudio` on top of that.

Comment: sorry, you are right. so it's lagging on pacat/man.
but not on audacity, that uses pulse.
I'm more confused now.

Comment: just being clear, I see the issue both on pulseaudio and portaudio using cmd line tools (for pulseaudio) and pyaudio (that uses portaudio)... and using audacity with alsa or pulse options works just fine.